# Determining a series convergence using root test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I just have a few quick questions on using the root test to determine the convergence a series.
If I get a series $\sum_{n=5}^\infty A_n$. What would the $n=5$ do? From my knowledge when I apply root test, I use the limit as $n\to\infty$ anyways and ignore the $n=5$.

Finally if I get a series such as $\left(\frac{2\ln(n)}{\ln(n)+|\sin(n)|}\right)^n$ and I use the root test to test for the limit as n-> infinity, what if part of the series -- $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\sin(n)| = DNE$? Would it make my whole series divergent or can I just choose to ignore it as it only takes on values $0$ to $1$ and $2\ln(n)/\ln(n)$ is far greater as $n\to\infty$?

Sorry if my questions are unclear, it's my first time posting here and I'm quite confused in the first place so it's hard for me to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0} a_n$ is convergent if and only if the partial sum sequence $ \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\right)_n$ is convergent which's equivalent  to the convergence of the sequence $ \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n_0}^n a_k\right)_n$ for all $n_0\in\Bbb N$ hence the convergence of a series doesn't depend of its first few terms.

For your second question notice that a series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0} a_n$ is divergent when the sequence $(a_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$.